# How to toggle visibility with the UILabel in UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, toggle

I have this chunk of code in my ViewController named `PlayViewController`:

```
words = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "PlayTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlayTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayTableViewCell.")
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.wordLabel.text = words[indexPath.row]

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.wordLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    return cell
}
```

And this is my code for TableViewCell named `PlayTableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class PlayTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        wordLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
        wordLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        wordLabel.isHidden = true

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

As expected, only my first `wordLabel` appears in my tableView.
My goal is to reveal the second `wordLabel` when the user swipes right or left anywhere on the screen and continue this way until the user reveal the last `wordLabel`.

I've found how to set the swipe part (only the swipe right, behaves weirdly when the left is added) but I can't figure out how to toggle `.isHidden` property when I detect the gesture.

I'm not sure to be on the right path with the cell configuration but because of the placing of the `wordLabel` inside `PlayTableViewCell`, it's hard to reach it outside the function `tableView`.

I can index neither `cell` nor `wordLabel` and I can't figure out how could I reach the right `wordLabel` to toggle its visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere store property for sum of revealed labels

```
var numberOfRevealedLabels = 1
```

then every time user swipes somewhere, increase this value and then reload data of your table view (you can reload it in `didSet` of your variable or after you increase this value in action which is called by swiping)

```
numberOfRevealedLabels += 1
```

Now, since cells are reusable, set visibility depending on if `indexPath.row` is less then or equal to `numberOfRevealedLabels - 1`

```
cell.wordLabel.isHidden = !(indexPath.row <= numberOfRevealedLabels - 1)
```

*... this also covers the case that `indexPath.row` is greater*

Comment: Should there be a didSet to refresh the tableView every time `numberOfRevealedLabels` is incremented?

Comment: @technology08 good point. He can also refresh data in action which is called by swiping.

Comment: Ah okay true. Either way. I submitted an edit showing the reload there, but it works either way.

Comment: I've tried to play with an incrementation but your idea sounds promising. I gonna try right now and keep you updated. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is working like a charm @RobertDresler! Time to dive into the implementation of swipe left ;)

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix issues about scrolling down a table made of dequeueReusableCells? I've just posted this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057392/how-to-prevent-uilabel-textcolor-to-change-in-a-dequeuereusablecell-when-scrolli -- looks like I need help once again 